# How to handle timeout issues with Maven Tycho?

Tags: maven, tycho, p2

My Maven/Tycho build starts failing from timeouts when resolving the target definition. I am behind a proxy, but the configuration works - it just fails somewhere in the middle of the resolution, and not always with the same repository.

Is there a way to increase the timeout or tries for tycho? And is there a way to disable fetching the indices, but keep downloading new artifacts?